# S3 folder disappears following BucketNotFound exception

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot

I'm writing code using AWS Java SDK, and in my Spring Boot application I use it to copy some files from one S3 folder to another. This works well when both origin folder and destination bucket exists.

However, during testing for end-cases, something strange happens: if I change the destination to be a non-existent bucket it throws a BucketNotFound Exception (as expected) but then the origin folder is deleted from S3.

I checked to confirm I do not delete the folder in the application, nor do I get any printout in the logs that suggest a delete. If I don't get the exception the origin folder survives with all its files - but if I do, the origin folder is gone.
My AWS S3 Java SDK dependency in pom.xml is:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
     <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
     <version>1.11.1034</version>
</dependency>
```

This is the AmazonS3 bean I use:

```
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class AWSConfig {

    public static final Regions REGION = Regions.US_EAST_1;

    @Bean
    public AmazonS3 s3Client() {

        return AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().
            withRegion(REGION).
            build();
    }

}
```

And this is the code for the copy:

```
public String copyFile(S3ObjectSummary file, AmazonS3URI originUri, 
                        AmazonS3URI destinationUri, boolean deleteOrig) throws Exception {
        String originFile = "s3://"+file.getBucketName()+"/"+file.getKey();
        AmazonS3URI origUri = new AmazonS3URI(originFile);
        logger.info("Origin file="+originFile);
        String suffix = originFile.substring(originUri.toString().length());
        if (suffix.startsWith("/")) suffix = suffix.substring(1);
        String destPath = destinationUri.getKey().endsWith("/")?
                               destinationUri.getKey():destinationUri.getKey()+"/";
        String destFile = "s3://"+destinationUri.getBucket()+"/"+destPath+suffix;
        logger.info("Destination file="+destFile);
        
        try {
            //check origin file exists
            listFiles(originFile);
            //Check dest bucket exists (this is where the exception will hit)
            listFiles("s3://"+destinationUri.getBucket());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("could not copy from origin "+originFile
                           +" to destination bucket s3://"+destinationUri.getBucket()
                           + " due to exception ",e);
            throw e; //This exception is clearly shown in the logs
        }
        
        AmazonS3URI destUri = new AmazonS3URI(destFile);
        
        //I originally got the exception here
        s3Client.copyObject(origUri.getBucket(), origUri.getKey(), destUri.getBucket(), destUri.getKey());
        if (deleteOrig) { //just to be on the safe side, this is set to false 
            deleteFile(originFile, file);
        }
        return destFile;
    }
```

And the listFiles (which I've added recently, to check if a read only command will trigger the same) is here:

```
public List<String> listFiles (String file) throws IOException {
    List<String> fileList = new ArrayList<>();
    if (file.startsWith("s3")) {
        AmazonS3URI fileURI = new AmazonS3URI(file);
        fileList.addAll(s3Client.listObjects(fileURI.getBucket(),fileURI.getKey())
                .getObjectSummaries()
                .stream()
                .map(x->"s3://"+x.getBucketName()+"/"+x.getKey())
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    } else {
        fileList.addAll(Files.list(Paths.get(file))
                .map(x->x.toAbsolutePath().toString())
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }
    return fileList;
}
```

And this is the log as the exception happens - and just before the folder drops:

```
2022-06-28 17:20:00 [scheduling-1] INFO  c.c.s.c.m.e.s.ETLManagerScheduler - Found 164 output files in smc-results/results/deid, belonging to 1 flows.
2022-06-28 17:20:00 [scheduling-1] INFO  c.c.s.c.m.e.s.ETLManagerScheduler - copying over files from smc-results/results/deid to smc-resuts/results/...
2022-06-28 17:20:00 [scheduling-1] INFO  c.c.s.c.m.e.flow.ETLFlowManager - Origin file=s3://smc-results/results/deid...
2022-06-28 17:20:00 [scheduling-1] INFO  c.c.s.c.m.e.flow.ETLFlowManager - Destination file=s3://smc-resuts/results/...
2022-06-28 17:20:00 [scheduling-1] ERROR c.c.s.c.m.e.flow.ETLFlowManager - could not copy from origin s3://smc-results/results/deid/... to destination bucket s3://smc-resuts due to exception com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The specified bucket does not exist (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 404; Error Code: NoSuchBucket; Request ID: NK8A8VRPVW5T0MWJ; S3 Extended Request ID: yWosaeT6c3z3h/JtI/2CCQUAm9mmMM69NW7vvgLAipKqAWqWvHtDmecoV7qc68fvS3HoWU2l2Bw=; Proxy: null)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1819)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleServiceErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1403)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1372)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1145)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:802)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:770)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:744)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:704)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:686)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:550)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:530)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5437)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5384)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5378)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.listObjects(AmazonS3Client.java:927)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.listObjects(AmazonS3Client.java:901)
    at ....listFiles(....java:259)
    at ...copyFile(....java:736)
    at ....copyFiles(....java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2022-06-28 17:20:00 [scheduling-1] WARN  c.c.s.c.m.e.s.ETLManagerScheduler - Could not list or move files from smc-results/results/deid to smc-resuts/results/... due to exception: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The specified bucket does not exist (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 404; Error Code: NoSuchBucket; Request ID: NK8A8VRPVW5T0MWJ; S3 Extended Request ID: yWosaeT6c3z3h/JtI/2CCQUAm9mmMM69NW7vvgLAipKqAWqWvHtDmecoV7qc68fvS3HoWU2l2Bw=; Proxy: null), S3 Extended Request ID: yWosaeT6c3z3h/JtI/2CCQUAm9mmMM69NW7vvgLAipKqAWqWvHtDmecoV7qc68fvS3HoWU2l2Bw=Wa
```

I double-checked that the folder exists for a good 10 minutes, but within a minute or two from the exception is vanishes. I even kept hitting "calculate total size" on the folder to confirm the files are there - until they're not.

Any ideas what might cause a sudden drop of a folder in S3? I started off thinking it was a copy command issue, but now even list commands cause this side effect.

Comment: There are typically no real folders in S3. They're virtual, and inferred from the presence of multiple objects with a common prefix ending in forward slash e.g. `dogs/bingo.png` and `dogs/elvis.jpg`.

Comment: @jarmod I know. But that just changes to question from how I lost one folder to how I lost 164 objects sharing the same prefix at once.

Comment: AWS is not deleting the objects. Your code is (or some other code you have running). I would search for all calls to `deleteFile()` or equivalent and make sure they are logged. I would also add an additional unconditional log to make sure you are actually running the same code that you are looking at.

Comment: @jarmod I will continue to investigate. All my delete commands are logged - and the area of code containing the deletes is never executed due to the exception. But I agree it is very unlikely an S3 issue.

Comment: Be sure to update when you find the root cause but I don't think it's in the code we're seeing here. BTW to test if a file exists in S3 you can simply use HeadObject.

Comment: @jarmod thanks! I’ll use it instead of the listFiles. I’ll also try to remove any code that does any deletion at all and see if the issue is still there. It feels very unclear.

Comment: If it becomes really difficult to diagnose, remove s3:DeleteObject permissions from the running process' IAM policies (or simply add a temporary explicit Deny), re-run the test code, and review the exception that should presumably happen.

Comment: Comment out the `deleteFile(originFile, file);` line and see if the problem still exists. It looks like it is deleting the source file even if the copy failed?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I removed all the delete references - and it worked! So somehow, somewhere a delete took place without any log printouts and without the code seeming to pass through. I'm investigating further to figure out what could trigger this strange behavior.

Comment: Looks like `deleteOrig` isn't working the way you expect.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I think I fixed it. There was a scheduler who pulled values from the DB and played a part in this - by marking failed runs correctly after the exception that flow didn’t run again. It’s strange the logs didn’t record it but it seems to be running correctly now. Thanks for the perspective and patience.